# Массив экземпляров разных классов

Tags: c#

прошу помощи с возникшим вопросом.
Единственный вариант, который я нашел, это через интерфейс.

Пример кода, main,

```
using Example;

ITest[] tst = new ITest[5];

tst[0] = new ClassA("Oleg", "Popov", 21 );
tst[1] = new ClassB("Dostoevsky", "Brothers Karamazov");
tst[2] = new ClassC("Passenger car", "Tesla", "2021");

tst[0].InterfaceMethod();
```

Интерфейс

```
namespace Example
{
    internal interface ITest
    {
        public void InterfaceMethod();
    }
}
```

Класс

```
namespace Example
{
    internal class ClassA : ITest
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _surname;
        public int Age;
        public static string staticTest = "";

        public ClassA(string name, string surname, int age)
        {
            _name = name;
            _surname = surname;
            Age = age;
        }

        public void InterfaceMethod()
        {

        }
        public void TestMethod()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

НО при этом ни одно поле / метод класса не доступны, кроме унаследованного от интерфейса метода.

Возможно ли создать массив экземпляров разных классов?

Comment: Да всё можно. Вплоть до того, что кастануть объекты всех классов в `object`, а потом обратно в нужный класс, когда он понадобится. Но зачем вам это всё, собственно, какую задачу вы перед собой ставите? Зачем вам разные классы в один массив класть, что вы потом с ними делать собираетесь? А ещё можно унаследовать от одного (абстрактного) класса все эти классы, например, тогда все поля класса-предка будут доступны.

Comment: Недавно начал изучать язык, поэтому такие вопросы. Не под конкретную задачу. Для саморазвития.

Comment: Для саморазвития почитайте про упаковку/распаковку. В `C#` это как-раз про то, как преобразовать любой объект в тип `object` и обратно. Это одна из базовых вещей, хотя давно уже и не нужная в реальной жизни. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing

Comment: Ок, спасибо большое

Comment: Сложить разношерстные классы в один массив - это нужно для того чтобы что-то потом с ними сделать. Дернуть у них что-то общее. А общий у них интерфейс. 
Простой пример у всех классов есть имя, и общий интерфейс содержит метод GetName, тогда можно через Foreach пройтись по всей коллекции разношерстных классов (Cat, Dog...) объединенных интерфейсом IAnimal и узнать как их всех зовут.

Comment: Lenz, спасибо за хороший пример